# How to call controller method in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

When i use URL(http://localhost/ci_framework/Temp).It successfully loaded my template.

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
     class Temp extends CI_Controller {
     public function index()
     {
        $this->load->view('index');
     }
     public function forward(){
         $this->load->view('index');
     }      
    }

?>
```

But when load same view(index) by adding their method name at the controller(http://localhost/ci_framework/Temp/forward). It fails to load Bootstrap files,java script files.

I have wasted 3 hours.Tell friends about possible solutions.Looking forward..

Comment: use full url for scripts files so that you will not get any issue

Comment: In second case i have given full url(controller/method)

Comment: check your base_url or site_url..whether your properly mentioned it...

Comment: like <script src="<?= base_url() . "/js/script.js"></script>

Comment: <script src=" <?php echo base_url(); >js/script.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are using relative paths for your CSS and JavaScript assets. Instead you should use absolute paths so that your asset includes are the same regardless of the current URL.

For example if you had `/css/style.css`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css" />
```

Comment: Access to Font at 'http://[::1]/ci_framework/assets/vendors/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

When i give absolute path it gives the following errror @MrCode

Answer (score 0):

`href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/css/yourfile.css">`

Comment: You should explain it what need to be done like MrCode has

Comment: @Lucifer : Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you mind extending your answer, for fellow programmers, to understand how exactly it helps to solve the problem?